# CSS causing elements to move upwards

Tags: html, css

I am having a very strange problem, and I'm not sure of the cause. Elements on my page are not sticking to their defined places, rather, they are 'jumping' upwards.

My current layout looks thus, with the HTML and CSS below:
[image: Current layout]

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Screening - Your movie database | Discover. Watch. Share.</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Screening is a brand new take on the traditional movie database, fusing social networking and multimedia to provide a clear, concise experience allowing you to share your favourite movies, and discover new classics.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Movies, Films, Screening, Discover, Watch, Share, experience, database, movie database, film database, share film, share films, discover film, discover films, share movie, share movies, discover movie, discover movies">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <header>

<p class="logo"><a href="index.php" id="logo">Screening</a></p>

<nav>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>      
    </ul>

</nav>

<section id="header_search">

    <form id="search" action="search.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" title="name" name="title" placeholder="search for a movie">
    </form>

</section>

</header>   
    <div id="content">

        <div id="home_banner">
            <h1>Discover. Watch. Share.</h1>
            <h2>Screening. Your movie database.</h2>
        </div>

        <form id="homesearch" action="search.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" title="name" name="title" placeholder="search for a movie">
        </form>

    </div>

    <footer>

<p class="logo"><a href="index.php" id="logo">Screening</a></p>

<nav>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" title="Home">Home</a> | </li>
        <li><a href="about.php" title="About">About</a> | </li>
        <li><a href="privacy.php" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>            
    </ul>

</nav>

<p id="copyright">©Screening 2012</p>

</footer>   
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* HTML reset */
html, * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* General styling */
body {
    font-family: 'RobotoLtRegular', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

/*Custom link styles*/

a:link {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: color .4s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .4s linear;
    -ms-transition: color .4s linear;
    -o-transition: color .4s linear;
    transition: color .4s linear;
}

a:visited {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #b70000;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.logo a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo a:hover {
    color: #b70000;
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Header styling */
header {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

header, footer {
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: .75em;
    clear: both;
}

header nav, .logo, footer nav {
    float: left;
}

header nav, footer nav, #header_search, #copyright {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

header li, footer li {
    display: inline;
}

#header_search {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}

#search input, #homesearch input {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    background-color: #2d3035;
    border: solid 4px #2a2e31;
}

#search input:focus, #homesearch input:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: #6a6f75;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#search input {
    width: 80%;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
}

/* Logo styling */
.logo {
    font-family: 'RobotoLtRegular', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    clear: left;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

/* Content wrapper */
#content {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px 15px 30px 15px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(203,203,203,0.2);
    background-image: url(assets/images/bkg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

/* Homepage */

#home_banner {
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

#home_banner h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    clear: both;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}

#home_banner h2, #search input, #homesearch input, #searchresults, #details .title {
    font-family: 'RobotoThRegular', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#home_banner h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    clear: both;
    border: solid 1px yellow;
}

#homesearch {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 80px auto 70px auto;
    clear: both;
}

#homesearch input {
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
}
```

I have added borders to each element I am having trouble with for clarity purposes. I had originally laid out everything correctly, however something has cocked up somewhere and I can't for the life of me figure it out; I've been struggling with this for weeks! I'm pretty sure it's something small and simple, but the solution is completely avoiding me.

Obviously, the intended result should be something like below (ignore the presentation of the search bar, this is an early mockup before the search bar was amended):
[image: Intended result]

Comment: What if you make your main div .ie the div with the "content" id as absolute and then position the child divs as "relative" ? That might solve your problem .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just kill the fixed line height for the body: line-height: 20px; <-- get rid of that.

Comment: Thank you! That's sorted everything perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve set the `line-height` on `<body>` to `20px`. Any elements without a `line-height` (e.g. your `<h1>` and `<h2>`) will inherit this line height size, even if their font size is much bigger.

It’s usually better to set line heights relative to the font size, i.e. don’t specify a pixel unit on them.

```
body {
    ...
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.25;/* This makes 20px the base line height, but it’ll get bigger for lines with a bigger font size */
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/8ZBzt/